# Join multiple columns, filling non-existent values with 0

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, staff_product and orders_with_over_20k_product.

staff_product

```
  STAFF_ID PRODUCT_ID
---------- ----------
         2          6
         2          4
         2          5
         2          7
         1          6
         1          4
         1          5
         1          7
         3          6
         3          4
         3          5
         3          7
```

orders_with_over_20k_product

```
  STAFF_ID PRODUCT_ID         PQ
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          4         20
         2          5        100
         1          5         10
         1          7          8
         2          7          1
         2          4         10
         2          6        100
         1          6        100
         3          4          1
```

I want to join them such that if there is a record in staff_product that has matching values in orders_with_over_20k_product then PQ will be copied, and if there isn't then PQ will be set to 0. I also want to preserve the order or product_id in staff_product (it's important for how my program handles this query). The desired output is as follows

```
  STAFF_ID PRODUCT_ID        PQ
---------- ---------- ---------
         2          6       100
         2          4        10
         2          5       100
         2          7         1
         1          6       100
         1          4        20
         1          5        10
         1          7         8
         3          6         0
         3          4         1
         3          5         0
         3          7         0
```

I'll be executing this select in a stored procedure and both the existing tables are currently views made of different queries. How would construct a query for my desired output?

Comment: can you please check whether your issue is resolved or not , please let me know in case if you have still any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select sp.*, coalesce(ow.pq, 0) as pq
from staff_product sp left join
     orders_with_over_20k_product ow
     on sp.staff_id = ow.staff_id and sp.product_id = ow.product_id
```

Comment: THis is almost correct, but i've jsut ran it on the server and it doesnt preserve the ordering of product_id, is this possible? I can change my Java if not but ideally i'd not need to.

Comment: @mexO: if you want a specific order, you have to use `order by` otherwise the database will return the rows in any order it likes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select
    p.*,
    coalesce(o.pq, 0) pq
from staff_product p
left join orders_with_over_20k_product o
    on o.product_id = p.product_id and o.staff_id = p.staff_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below `SQL` code for this issue.

```
SELECT A.STAFF_ID
    ,A.PRODUCT_ID
    ,coalesce(B.PQ, 0) AS PQ
FROM staff_product AS A
LEFT JOIN orders_with_over_20k_product AS B ON A.STAFF_ID = B.STAFF_ID
    AND A.PRODUCT_ID = B.PRODUCT_ID
```